# How to select a specific field in a DTSX file in powershell

Tags: powershell, ssis

How do I select a specific field in a DTSX file using powershell? So that i can change its value.

Here is the following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DTS:Executable xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts" DTS:ExecutableType="SSIS.Package.2">
    ..
   <DTS:Configuration>
      ..
      <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ConfigurationType">1</DTS:Property>
      <DTS:Property DTS:Name="ConfigurationString">change me</DTS:Property>
      ..
   </DTS:Configuration>
   ..
</DTS:Executable>
```

How do i access the field? I've been trying to print something by doing:

```
$xml.Executable.Configuration.ConfigurationString
```

or

```
$xml.Executable.Configuration.Property.ConfigurationString
```

But it doesn't print anything.

Thanks in advance and best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
[xml]$xml = gc c:\myxml.xml

$xml.Executable.Configuration.Property | ? { $_.'#text' -eq 'change me'} | % { $_.'#text' = "Changed" }

$xml.Save( "c:\mynewxml.xml" )
```

Edit after comment:

```
$xml.Executable.Configuration.Property | ? { $_.name -eq 'configurationstring'} | % { $_.'#text' = "Changed" }
```

Comment: The thing is that I wont know what the value will be. What I know, is that i want to change what is between "Configuration String". But thanks!

Comment: @Bparra Edited my answer. Try it and give feedback :)